Does parayana of the fourth chapter of the Chandipath reduce bad karmas?
Suppose in life one becomes extremely regretful of the bad karmas in this life from his childhood. He also thinks contemplates on the bad karmas of his previous lives which may be so bad that he is terrified to experience the fruits. Suppose this person wants to erase all the bad karmas and try redeem himself what should he do ?
Also which mantras can be chanted to reduce the bad karmas- is the fourth chapter of Chandipath a good way to reduce the bad karmas?
